# Where can I see results of moderator election 2011

Tags: support, election

Recently I have voted for the moderator election on SO but I do not see any link which will take me to the results of moderator elections. Where can I see results of recently concluded moderator election 2011?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit https://stackoverflow.com/election

In fact, appending `/election` should work for any site that is having or has recently finished an election.

Further examples:

https://superuser.com/election
https://serverfault.com/election
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/election

and so on; even more (and a rough schedule) are in [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/moderator-messages/) blog post.

Comment: Latest [Stack Overflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/welcome-our-new-trilogy-moderators-for-2011/) welcomes the new mods