# Include information about elections in the newsletter

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, election, newsletter

It is currently [community moderator election at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/election). I just got the Ask Ubuntu Weekly Newsletter and it does not mention the election. An election is a very important event for a Stack Exchange site. Therefore I would like to suggest that whenever a Stack Exchange site has an election that site's newsletter will mention the election.

Since elections happens rarely on a site and it a very important event I think that it should be included in its own box *directly* after the first heading of the newsletter. It could read something like

> ### [Site name] [year] community moderator election
>
> [The community moderator election of [Site
> name]](https://stackexchange.com/election) is currently in the
> primary/election phase. Please cast your vote!

for the primary and election phases. And something like

> ### [Site name] [year] community moderator election
>
> [The community moderator election of [Site
> name]](https://stackexchange.com/election) is currently in the
> nomination phase. Take your chance to review the nominees!

for the nomination phase.

Comment: You know what might spur this along to possibly being [status-planned]? If you could give a little idea of what the blurb for an election warning should look like. ♪

Comment: @GraceNote done. Obviously it can be improved so anyone who has ideas how to, please contribute!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Current community moderator elections now get top billing in the newsletter!

For example, here's the top of the [current Mathematics newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=math.stackexchange.com):

[image]