# Newsletter says to cast a vote "by" the date of the end of the nomination phase instead of after

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, wording, community-digests

Recently I got an email with the MathOverflow newsletter (digest) which contained the following text:

> 2022 Community Moderator Election
>
> The community moderator election is currently in the nomination phase.
>
> [Please cast your vote by September 26!](https://mathoverflow.net/election)

However, since September 26 is the [end of the nomination phase](https://mathoverflow.net/election/3), the text about voting doesn't seem right. (I can only cast a vote *after* September 26 - when the nomination phase ends.)

I suppose that the text was included as a result of this feature request: [Include information about elections in the newsletter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121562). But the wording suggested there for the nomination phase was different.

This text was only shown in the e-mail - not [in the preview](https://mathoverflow.net/digest/preview).

Comment: ...Yep, right you are – for some reason, the relevant code says exactly this. It makes sense that this "Please cast your vote by [end of current phase]" wording is used for the subsequent primary phase (if there is one) and voting phase, but it doesn't make much sense to use this phrasing during the nomination phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of January 30<sup>th</sup>, 2023, the default newsletter text for the nomination phase has changed to

> If you would like to run in this election, please nominate yourself by {StartDate}

The text remains as it was for other phases.